# Music Genre classification based on plays in radios

Tags: r, machine-learning, bigdata, classification, cluster-analysis

I have data about thousand of tracks being played in different radio stations. Numbers are play count for each track in each radio station:

```
         station1    station2    station3    station4 ...     
track1      0            2          5            0
track2      1            0          0            0 
track3      3           20          2            0
track4      0            1          0            1
track5      0            0          0            3
     .
     . 
     .
```

Can I use this data to automatically classify:

1. The radio stations genres
2. The tracks genres

How can I do this using R?

Comment: you can identify clusters of tracks that go together on which stations, but without some knowledge about what the tracks and stations are, you won't be able to say "station 1 plays rock music". I would look at the clustering task view and find something similar to your problem: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html

Comment: @bartektartanus I understand the "too broad" flag. G. Grothendieck understood perfectly the question and gave a great straight forward answer, which already has 3 votes up. I think this question should be reopened and give the opportunity for others to respond like him

Answer (score 3):

Read in the data and use kmeans on the columns to cluster the stations and on rows to cluster the tracks.  `k` is the number of genres you wish to use.  You will need to determine what each cluster means.  Note that cluster 1 in the first `kmeans` run is not necessarily the same genre as cluster 1 in the second.

```
Lines <- "station1    station2    station3    station4
track1      0            2          5            0
track2      1            0          0            0 
track3      3           20          2            0
track4      0            1          0            1
track5      0            0          0            3"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
k <- 2 # number of genres
kmeans(DF, k) # cluster stations
kmeans(t(DF), k) # cluster tracks
```